# How to encode array of Int into Soap call

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I am trying to call a method in a WCF service. I can hit the method and it can receive all the parameters except an array of integers. The content of my calls looks like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action>Test/TestContract/DeletePersons</a:Action>
    <a:To>@Location</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <DeletePersons xmlns="Test">
      <groupname>connStringDatabase</groupname>
      <username>@Username</username>
      <password>@Password</password>
      <insurer>@Insurer</insurer>
      <onlyfromself>false</onlyfromself>
      <identification_number/>
      <initials/>
      <firstname>@FirstName</firstname>
      <name>@LastName</name>
      <gender/>
      <dateofbirth/>
      <personIds>
        <int>123</int>
      </personIds>
    </DeletePersons>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The method in the contract of the service looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Test")]
public interface TestContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestResponse DeletePersons(string groupname, string username, string password, string insurer, List<int> personIds);
}
```

As I said, all the parameters (strings) are received correctly while the **personIds** array is received but it's empty. How should encode it into the XML request? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use array `int[]` instead of list?

Comment: @arekzyla Yes I have!